# User page access rights in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

There are several users who logged onto my project, Now i want to give rights to a particular user to access only particular pages, like the sales head can able to access any of his sales team member user page, but the sales team members cannot able to access the sales head page.so how to provide rights based on the user for accessing the webpages?

Comment: This will get you started 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/281573/ASP-NET-Membership-and-Role-Provider

Answer (score 0):

Either you can choose to use the built in Membership features in asp.net or you can choose to implement your own custom Membership- and Role Provider.

The built in asp.net Membership Providers is a good option if your don't have to many users to manage.

However if you already have these users and their roles already managed somewhere else Active Directory, Sql Database etc then I would implement my own Membership- and Role Providers. You can read more about it in this example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6tc47t75(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You need to add roles to your application. By adding roles and membership, users will have access to specific pages as you have assigned. They will need to login first to use your application!

There a number of ways to implement roles. One is on directory bases. You give specific privileges to a directory. The second is page by page basis. You use the function IsUserInRole on the page where you want to grant access.

You need to read some documentation on this. They are not too heard to implement, much of functionality is available ready made, for example logins controls are available that can be used without coding.